# How do I get the error code of netsh?

Tags: c#, cmd

I capture the **output** and the **exit code** of a process like this:

```
Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        FileName = Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\netsh.exe",
        Arguments = "http delete urlacl url=http://+:8080/my/Url/Suffix"
    }
};
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();

int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

When I inspect the **exit code**, it is

> 1

When I inspect the **output** of the process, it is

> URL reservation delete failed, Error: 2
> The system cannot find the file specified.

The output is exactly what I expect it to be. I am trying to delete a reservation that does not exist. What I need is the error code buried inside of the output. Do I need to write my own custom parser that takes into account all of the weird messages that netsh might throw at me?

Is there a simple way to get the error code?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use a regex.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's the way I'm going until I find a better method. I'm worried that my regex will be poor unless I know everything that `netsh delete urlacl` can possibly output.

Comment: RegEx is even worse if you want your application to work for Windows installations running in other languages. I just had the honor of seeing my application completely fail on a French Windows, because all the outputs were in French.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have come up with a good solution to this, assuming you don't mind using RegEx.

From the samples I have seen of the French output message syntax, I assume this RegEx should work for any language, but I have not tested it.

- `^\\r\\n.+: (\d+)\\r\\n.+\\r\\n$`
- [RegEx101.com test](https://regex101.com/r/MxlhEZ/1)

Example code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = ...;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

if (exitCode == 0)
    return 0; // success.
else if (exitCode == 1)
{
    const string NETSH_ERROR_REGEX = "^\\\\r\\\\n.+: (\\d+)\\\\r\\\\n.+\\\\r\\\\n$";
    Match match = Regex.Match(output, NETSH_ERROR_REGEX);
    if (match.Groups is object && int.TryParse(match.Groups.Values.Single().Value, out int i))
        return i; // netsh error code.
}
throw new Exception($"\"{startInfo.FileName} {startInfo.Arguments}\" exited with {exitCode}. Output: \"{output.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n")}\"");
```

Comment: You could simplify your regex to `@"Error:\s(\d+)"`

Comment: The word "Error" is isn't used in other languages, hence the reason for this whole question. For example in French it is "erreurÿ" instead. Check the RegEx101 link in my answer.